# FreeRTOS x86 in virtual environment

Tags: virtual-machine, freertos

I've been reading about FreeRTOS and seems like its widely used on microcontrollers and microprocessors like RasPi/BBB etc. I also read that it can be run on x86 platform and I want to test it.

Can I run FreeRTOS as a VM on virtual box or VMware?
Whats the best way to use FreeRTOS on x86 platform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to use FreeRTOS on x86 is to run an available FreeRTOS simulator.

e.g. [FreeRTOS Windows port](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Windows-Simulator-Emulator-for-Visual-Studio-and-Eclipse-MingW.html):

> This allows FreeRTOS to be run in a Windows environment - although
>   true real time behaviour cannot be achieved. Demo projects are
>   provided for both Eclipse with MingW (GCC) and Visual Studio 2010
>   Express Edition.

See the *Richard's answer* on this topic:
[Building FreeRTOS for x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542618/building-freertos-for-x86)

> but  [...] the timing is all over the place and simulated time is much lower than
>   real time (because the timing resolution and accuracy in Windows is so
>   low compared to a real time system).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hugo, So basically there is no way to set it up in VMware or any virtual environment but only FreeRTOS simulators?

Comment: Also, do you know how to run FreeRTOS as an OS on a CPU?

Comment: FreeRTOS is not in the list of supported guest operating systems for [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes), [VMware](https://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/home.html), [Parallels](https://download.parallels.com/desktop/v12/docs/en_US/Parallels%20Desktop%20User%27s%20Guide/33321.htm).

About CPU virtualization, I think it is possible to run it through QEMU which emulates Cortex-M processor cores: [Can FreeRTOS run on Qemu for ARM Cortex M?](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/October_2017/freertos_Can_FreeRTOS_run_on_Qemu_for_ARM_Cortex_M_37fa61acj.html).